# how to apply rounded border to only left side of element

Tags: html, css, styling

I want to achieve this

[image: expected]

But using this css

```
border-left: 3px solid red;
border-radius: 3px;
```

It is producing this result

[image: my result]

plz ignore spacing, i will add that

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your title does not match the images.

Comment: You are asking how to apply to only one side but you want on all sides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius`

```css
.div{
margin-top:40px;
  width:50px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:50px;
  background:red;
  transform:rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: thats exactly what i an getting bhai..but i want round edged on all sides!

Comment: How did this get accepted?  If you add the text `2.1 Cr` inside or outside the `div` you'll get weird effects.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [`pseudo-classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) in order to create your red bar. Try this:

```css
span {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3em;
}

span::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>2.1 Cr</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

try this

[image: Link to the example result]

Fiddle file:

https://jsfiddle.net/swuzqpbt/

```
htmlelement {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px auto;;
}
htmlelement ::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    width: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi this is my desired result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjc0Z.png

Comment: i want 3px border radius on the left border

Comment: @robbstark added new example, it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

The reason your approach doesn't work is that `border-radius` applies to the corners of the *entire element*, not of the left border.

From strictly eyeballing it, the other answers break when you have multiple block elements inside the parent and/or a variable height.

Stack Overflow actually uses blockquotes with the functionality you want:

> <- See how the border is rounded on all sides?

I have narrowed down what they do:

```css
blockquote {
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

blockquote:before {
  background: #c8ccd0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
 <p>first p</p>
 <p>second p</p>
</blockquote>
```

Works with spans, too. Obviously you wouldn't have block elements inside a span, but it's nice to have a solution that's agnostic. And again, no explicit height is required, the border is as long as it needs to be:

```css
span {
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

span:before {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<span>2.1 Cr</span>
```

The reason this solution works is the relative positioning of the element along with the absolute positioning of the `before` pseudo element, resulting in a position on the left. And the pseudo element has four corners that can then all be rounded.